# Pygame only draws when window has a square shape

Tags: python, pygame

This code draws a few rects on a surface. The rects positions are based on grid intersections.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

DISPLAY_SIZE =(201, 201)
SQUARE_SIZE = 100

main_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY_SIZE)

canvas_surface = pygame.Surface(DISPLAY_SIZE)
canvas_surface.fill('white')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_grid_lines(surface, field_size):

    """
    This function will draw grid lines into a given surface.
    The size of the fields (squares) formed by the grid is 
    defined by 'field_size'
    """

    surface_width = surface.get_width()
    surface_height = surface.get_height()

    current_x_cord = 0
    current_y_cord = 0
        
    done_drawing_grid = False

    while not done_drawing_grid:

        top_side = (current_x_cord, 0)
        bottom_side = (current_x_cord, surface_height)

        left_side = (0, current_y_cord)
        right_side = (surface_width, current_y_cord)

        # Draw line on the 'x' axis
        pygame.draw.line(surface, "black", left_side, right_side)

        # Draw line on the 'y' axis
        pygame.draw.line(surface, "black",top_side, bottom_side)

        # Increase 'x' and 'y' values
        current_x_cord += field_size
        current_y_cord += field_size

        done_x_lines = current_x_cord > surface_width
        done_y_lines = current_y_cord > surface_height
        
        if done_x_lines and done_y_lines:
            done_drawing_grid = True

rect_list = []

for row in range(0, main_screen.get_width(), SQUARE_SIZE):
    for column in range(0, main_screen.get_height(), SQUARE_SIZE):

        rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (21,21))
        rect.center = (column, row)
        rect_list.append(rect)

for rect in rect_list:
    pygame.draw.rect(canvas_surface, "black", rect)
    print(rect.center)

draw_grid_lines(canvas_surface, SQUARE_SIZE)

main_screen.blit(canvas_surface, (0,0))

pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            raise SystemExit

    pygame.event.wait()

    # clock.tick(60)
```

It works as expected, but only if the main screen dimensions are equal for x and y. Otherwise, a few rects are not draw.
Changing `DISPLAY_SIZE` to `(201, 101)` will draw only 4 rects when it should draw 6.
`print(rect.center)` tells me the rects are there. The `Rect` objects exist, I even checked using `isinstance`, but for some reason they are only draw when x and y are the same.

This is the original version of the code (the first one is simplified for convenience):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

DISPLAY_SIZE =(201, 101)
SQUARE_SIZE = 100

foo = pygame.RESIZABLE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.HWSURFACE

main_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY_SIZE, foo)
main_screen.fill('white')

class CanvasSurface(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__(self, size):
        super().__init__(size)
        self.fill("white")

    def resize(self, new_size):
        super().__init__(new_size)
        self.fill("white")

canvas_surface = CanvasSurface(DISPLAY_SIZE)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def draw_grid_lines(surface, field_size):

    """
    This function will draw grid lines into a given surface.
    The size of the fields (squares) formed by the grid is 
    defined by 'field_size'
    """

    surface_width = surface.get_width()
    surface_height = surface.get_height()

    current_x_cord = 0
    current_y_cord = 0
        
    done_drawing_grid = False

    while not done_drawing_grid:

        top_side = (current_x_cord, 0)
        bottom_side = (current_x_cord, surface_height)

        left_side = (0, current_y_cord)
        right_side = (surface_width, current_y_cord)

        # Draw line on the 'x' axis
        pygame.draw.line(surface, "black", left_side, right_side)

        # Draw line on the 'y' axis
        pygame.draw.line(surface, "black",top_side, bottom_side)

        # Increase 'x' and 'y' values
        current_x_cord += field_size
        current_y_cord += field_size

        done_x_lines = current_x_cord > surface_width
        done_y_lines = current_y_cord > surface_height
        
        if done_x_lines and done_y_lines:
            done_drawing_grid = True


rect_list = []

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            raise SystemExit

        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            canvas_surface.resize(event.size)

            rect_list.clear()
            for row in range(0, main_screen.get_width(), SQUARE_SIZE):
                for column in range(0, main_screen.get_height(), SQUARE_SIZE):

                    rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (21,21))
                    rect.center = (column, row)
                    rect_list.append(rect)
                    pygame.draw.rect(canvas_surface, "black", rect)


    draw_grid_lines(canvas_surface, SQUARE_SIZE)

    main_screen.blit(canvas_surface, (0,0))

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```

With this one, it's easier to see the change. Try expanding the pygame window by dragging the border, or even changing the code, and you will understand.
When dragging the left/right border, no rect is drawn, but when you expand the top/bottom part, the rects are drawn.
Again, the rects are there (you can check in `rect_list`), but they are not being drawn.

Am i forgetting something?

After `if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:` using `main_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size)` does nothing.

I also tried to force a rect from rect_list to be draw by using `pygame.draw.rect(canvas_surface, "red", rect_list[-1])`, also nothing.

```
for rect in rect_list:
    print(rect.center)
```

The above prints every rect center. By checking the coordinates, every rect is in it's desired position. I just don't understand why it is not being drawn.

PS:
I am using the latest pygame update;
`draw_grid_lines` is only used for convenience. It can be removed if necessary;
English is not my first language, sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "row" is a line of a structure and a "column" is an upright element of a structure. So the "columns" are the elements along the x-axis and bounded by the width of the screen and the "rows" are the elements along the y-axis and bounded by the height. Swap `row` and `column` in the inner and outer loop:

```py
for column in range(0, main_screen.get_width(), SQUARE_SIZE):
    for row in range(0, main_screen.get_height(), SQUARE_SIZE):

        rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (21,21))
        rect.center = (column, row)
        rect_list.append(rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first coordinate should be `row` not `column`.

The solution is simple, change

```
rect.center = (column, row)
```

to

```
rect.center = (row, column)
```